# MvcCodeRouting: "Link" views to the same route as the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a Controller structure that looks like this:

```
[Controllers]
  [Users]
    [PlayersController.cs]
    [ServicesController.cs]
```

Where `Players` and `Services` are the two different types of users.

If i call the controller like this: `localhost:xxxx/Users/Players/` index is being called, as expected, but my View is not rendered. My view is under `~/Views/Users/Players/Index.cshtml` but ASP.NET is not looking for it under that folder.

I read that I should use `EnableCodeRouting` but I'm not sure where and how to use it:
https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting/blob/master/docs/api/MvcCodeRouting/CodeRoutingExtensions/EnableCodeRouting_1.md

I added a that method under `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` but it's never being called.

How do I, without typing in the View link in the controller, tell MvcCodeRouting where my View is located?

I.e. I want to use `return View(vm)` not `return View("~/Views/Users/Players/index.cshtml")`.

Answer (score 0):

In global.asax.cs.Application_Start() add this: `RegisterViewEngines(ViewEngines.Engines);`

And in the same class create this method:

```
void RegisterViewEngines(ViewEngineCollection viewEngines)
        {

            // Call AFTER you are done making changes to viewEngines
            viewEngines.EnableCodeRouting();
        }
```